# excel stop a user accessing a cell if background colour is black

Tags: excel, vba, 2d-games

I am trying to build a simple game (Maze) in excel 2003. I need a Macro that stops a user selecting a cell (using arrow keys) if they have a black background colour.

I cant seem to find anyway to stop this happening (regardless of the colour).

Any hints or help would be great.

Thanks.

Tom

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim x As Integer
Dim y As String
Dim z As Integer
Dim answer As Integer
Dim OldRange As Range



x = Range("AL4").Value
y = Range("AL5").Value
z = Range("AL6").Value
accessory = Range("AL7").Value

'ColorIndex 1 is Black
If Target.Cells(1, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 1 Then
    OldRange.Select
Else
    Set OldRange = Target
End If
```

I have tried this: I'm confused as to where I am going wrong!
In the ThisWorkbook I have added at the very top:
    Option Explicit
    Private OldRange As Range

I have then added the following to my Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range) area:

```
If Target.Cells(1, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 1 Then
    OldRange.Select
Else
    Set OldRange = Target
End If
```

I am still getting a Debug error on the OldRange.Select line.

**UPDATE**
I was being slow! Sorry!
Working now much appreciated.

Thanks.

Tom

Comment: You could look into the worksheet_SelectionChange event

Comment: This won't work because `OldRange` will be `Nothing` inside this sub. You have to declare it in the worksheet code as a private member, i.e. outside the sub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution for you (enter this code in worksheet code block):

```
Private OldRange As Range

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    'ColorIndex 1 is Black
    If Target.Cells(1, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 1 Then
        OldRange.Select
    Else
        Set OldRange = Target
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I have added the code that you have provided: in the following - it is giving a debug error at the moment: </br> Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim x As Integer
Dim y As String
Dim z As Integer
Dim answer As Integer
Dim OldRange As Range



x = Range("AL4").Value
y = Range("AL5").Value
z = Range("AL6").Value
accessory = Range("AL7").Value

    'ColorIndex 1 is Black
    If Target.Cells(1, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 1 Then
    OldRange.Select
    Else Set OldRange = Target
    End If

Comment: You have to declare OldRange in the Worksheet code, not the event handler!